# Show context menu from code behind

Tags: android, contextmenu, show, code-behind

This might be a simple question, but I've been looking around and can't find the answer. Is there any code to show the context menu on Android from a code, instead of pressing the menu button? E.g. when I touch the screen then it'll call the context menu?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Call `openContextMenu()` on your `Activity` whenever you want to open it. Note that this is a rather unusual UI pattern, one that your users may not expect.

Answer (score 7):

```
 OnClickListener onClick_Show_Contextmenu = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((Activity) context).openContextMenu(v);
            }

        };

        findViewById(R.id.xxx).setOnClickListener(onClick_Show_Contextmenu);

        registerForContextMenu(findViewById(R.id.xxx));
        findViewById(R.id.xxx).setLongClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use any of the following:

1. [**openContextMenu**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) as shown here:

> ```
> registerForContextMenu(view); 
> openContextMenu(view);
> unregisterForContextMenu(view);
> ```

1. [**setOnCreateContextMenuListener**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnCreateContextMenuListener%28android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener%29)
2. [**showContextMenuForChild**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#showContextMenuForChild%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
view.showContextMenu();
```

on your view.